# Light's speed constancy

Tags: visible-light, relativity

Trying to understand the special relativity I faced a problem,and have a question, well, with the speed of light being constant in every frame, the operation s=d/t (s for the speed of light d: distance and t: time) should also be constant for every frame, but according to Lorentz transformations: presuming that in the first frame an observer calculates the following: a ray of light travelling 3*10^8m in 1s, that makes v=d/t=3*10^8m/s which is correct, an other observer in an other frame moving 0,9998 the speed of light away from the first one sees the ray of light travelling shorter: 6*10^6m in 50s (according to Lorentz transformations with gamma being 50) which makes a speed of v=d/t=12*10^4m/s. So using the Lorentz transformations (which are d'=(1/gamma)*d and t'=gammma*t) I get false results.  What is wrong? My instincts tells that if the distance appears shorter for the 2nd observer time should appear shorter like 0.02s in order to have the correct speed of light, but the Lorentz says it is 50 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

The Lorentz transformations are actually
$$t'=\gamma(t-\frac{vd}{c^2})$$
$$d' = \gamma(d-vt),$$
where $v=0.9998c\ \text{m/s}$ is the speed of the moving observer with respect to the stationary observer. We also have $t=1\ \text{s}$ and $d=c\ \text{m}$. The factor $\gamma\approx50$, so you calculated that correctly.

Let's substitute all the known values and calculate $t'$ and $d'$:
$$t'=50(1-\frac{0.9998c\times c}{c^2})\approx 0.01 \ \text{s}$$
$$d'=50(c - 0.9998c\times1)\approx 0.01c\ \text{m}$$

We can now conclude that the speed of light as measured by the moving observer is
$$c'=\frac{d'}{t'}=\frac{0.01c}{0.01}=c.$$ The speed of light is the same for both observers, which is what we expected.

In the end, your instincts were correct. If the time interval is shrunk for an observer, then the space interval must have shrunk by the same factor in order to keep the speed of light constant. In this example, both intervals shrunk by a factor of 100. This is only the case with things moving at the speed of light, though.